# sorting a multidimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

`[["2010-01-10", 2], ["2010-01-09", 5], ["2009-12-11", 3], ["2009-12-12", 12], ["2009-12-13", 0]]`

I just want to sort it by the second value in each group and return the highest one, like i want to the output to be `12` with the given input above.

**update**

I might add that I made this into an array using `to_a`, from a hash, so if there is away to do the same with a hash that would be even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this on your hash:

```
hash.values.max
```

If you only need the highest element, there is no need to sort it!

Comment: I'm almost embarrassed for asking the question now. Thanks +1

Answer (score 31):

To sort by second value

```
x=[["2010-01-10", 2], ["2010-01-09", 5], ["2009-12-11", 3], ["2009-12-12", 12], ["2009-12-13", 0]]

x.sort_by{|k|k[1]}
=> [["2009-12-13", 0], ["2010-01-10", 2], ["2009-12-11", 3], ["2010-01-09", 5], ["2009-12-12", 12]]
```

Comment: just to note: `sort_by` requires Ruby 1.8.7+

Answer (score 8):

Call the `sort` method on your hash to sort it.

```
hash = hash.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
```

Then convert your hash to an array and extract the first value.

```
result = hash.to_a[0][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the key-value pair with the max value:

```
hash.max_by {|key, val| val} # => ["2009-12-12", 12]
```

requires Ruby 1.8.7+